# DEB package can't install its dependencies when using dpkg

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, deb, packaging

I have a deb package which I build but when I test it with dpkg (before put it in our repo) it can't install the dependencies put in DEBIAN/control file.

```
Package: package-name
Version: 1.0-1
Section: bla
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Depends: openjdk-8-jre
Maintainer: user@mail.com
Description: BLa bla
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. `dpkg` itself is not a dependency resolver, `apt` provides that functionality. You will need to first install the required dependencies if you wish to install something with `dpkg -i`, or you will need to run `apt-get -f install` after, which should pull in the missing dependencies if they are available.

Comment: So basically the thing above will work when installed with apt-get install?

Comment: No, `apt` does not install arbitrary local deb files. It installs packages available from a repository. You need to `dpkg -i $file` and then run `apt-get -f install` to install the dependencies. Or you can just manually install the dependencies first, and `dpkg -i $file` will not give you any errors.

Comment: If you originally had used `sudo apt install /path/to/your/.deb` and if any required dependencies were in your enabled sources then the externel .deb & it's deps would have been installed. (with 16.04 on

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install `gdebi` (package installer)

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

or [Gdebi Download for Linux (deb)](https://pkgs.org/download/gdebi)

then you can open deb files using the gdebi GUI.........